# Is there a difference in speed between mov bx,ax and mov bh,ah?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, mov

Is there a difference in speed between `mov bx,ax` and `mov bh,ah` in a 16-bit MS-DOS application for an 8086 architecture?

Comment: Microoptimizations should only be considered when you cannot improve the employed algorithms. A single instruction is hardly going to produce noticeable effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in doubt, profile. But it's very unlikely in this case. From what I gleaned from the Intel 64 and IA32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual it appears to be that they both perform identically but usually slower than their 32-bit or 64-bit counterparts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To which page are you referring?

Answer (score 5):

You don't specify the architecture, but at least in `8086`, `286`, `386` and `486` they execute in the same number of clocks: 2 clocks in `8088/8086`, `286` and `386` for either instruction, 1 clock in `486` for either instruction. See [link](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/mov.html).

Comment: The processors you mention are no longer relevant today. Worthless answer IHMO

Comment: @hirschhornsalz AFAIK at least 386 is used still in embedded systems. For example according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386) Blackberry 950 and Nokia 9000 Communicator used it. So 386 is still relevant, although obviously not for mainstream desktop computing.

Comment: Well, my Communicator 9500 gave up on me a year ago. I doubt there are that many Communicator 9000 or Blackberry 950 remaining that it can be called relevant today.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz Who cares about "relevant", this is a system that runs MS-DOS. The answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: @MarioVilas When I was talking about "relevant" I meant the architecture, not the OS. nrz already corrected me, and I have long retracted my downvote.